# How to change luminance in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a package in R that allows me to give several photographs the same average luminance?

The photographs I have are generally low definition. I have seen the package `'magick'` but there is no mention of luminance as something that can be altered.

Although I am pretty new to the physics of light as I understand it luminance and brightness are different so altering the brightness is not quite enough.

Comment: If you can change color space from RGB to YUV, then, IIRC Y channel controls luminance.

Comment: @TanveerBadar that is IIRC Y channel as part of the magick package?

Comment: The `colorscience` pkg has a RGB2YUV function. Agree question should be closed as request for package rec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `imager`, you can change the color space of an image (from RGB to HSL/HSV/HSI/YUV/YCbCR). In one color space, you can manipulate each channel as you like.

Here, I convert `im` from RGB to [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) (corresponding to one luma (Y) and two chrominance (UV) channels). Then, as an example, I incrementally increase the luma:

```
library(imager)

im <- load.image(system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager'))

im.yuv <- RGBtoYUV(im) # convert from RGB to YUV

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(im) 
for (i in rep(0.2, 2)){
  im.yuv[,,1,1] <- im.yuv[,,1,1] + i  # the last dimension gives the channel; 1:Y 2:U 3:V
  im.cor <- YUVtoRGB(im.yuv) # convert back from YUV to RGB
  plot(im.cor)
}
```

[image]